# Create Typescript class instance from POJO

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

In ES6 I can have:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor({a, b, c} = {}) {
    this._a = a;
    this._b = b;
    this._c = c;
  }
}

let data = {"a":3, "b": 44, "c": 55};
let myObject = new MyClass(data);
```

and it just works.  Typescript things I haven't provided values for the fields.  So how does one do this in TypeScript.  Preferably by changing the constructor parameters at most.  I don't want some long winded hung of stuff to make it happen.

If this cannot be done it is very very bad news that breaks imho much of the goodness of javascript and ES6 and takes me back to Java and such where I end up writing some static fromData(..) method.    Which would really tick me off.

So is there a way?

Comment: `myObject = new MyClass(); Object.assign(myObject, pojoData);` - the only risk here is that `pojoData` do not satisfies `MyClass` types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in TypeScript; you just need to add the type information:

```
class MyClass {
  _a: number;
  _b: number;
  _c: number;
  constructor({ a, b, c }: { a?: number, b?: number, c?: number } = {}) {
    this._a = a;
    this._b = b;
    this._c = c;
  }
}

let data = { "a": 3, "b": 44, "c": 55 };
let myObject = new MyClass(data);
```

Comment: I have noticed it also gets happier if I add default values.  Which effectively does the same thing I am guessing as it uses the types of the defaults to infer type.